# Crawler Spider: Spider Error processing raises NotImpmentedError

Tags: scrapy

I've been trying to get my head around scrapy but I'm not having much luck getting beyond the basics. When I run my spider i get a **spider error processing** the page and a spider exemption that isn't implemented yet but if I use `scrapy fetch` the html response is outputted so its not that the site is not available. The output is included below along with my Items, spider and settings values

**Items.py**

```
class MycrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
# define the fields for your item here like:
# name = scrapy.Field()
title = scrapy.Field()
files = scrapy.Field()
file_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

**mycrawler.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from librarycrawler.items import LibrarycrawlerItem
class CrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mycrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com"
    ]
    #LinkExtractor(),
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(),callback='scrape_page', follow=True)
    )

    def scrape_page(self,response):
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body,"html.parser")
        ScrapedPageTitle = page_soup.title.get_text()
        item = LibrarycrawlerItem()
        item['title'] =ScrapedPageTitle
        item['file_urls'] = response.url

        yield item
```

**Settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = { 
'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline':300,
}

FILES_STORE = 'C:\MySpider\mycrawler\ExtractedText'
```

**Terminal Output**

```
[scrapy] C:\MySpider\mycrawler>scrapy crawl mycrawler -o mycrawler.csv
2016-06-03 16:11:47 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: mycrawler)
2016-06-03 16:11:47 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2016-06-03 16:11:47 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'mycrawler.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'mycrawler.csv', 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['mycrawler.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'mycrawler', 'USER_AGENT': 'mycrawler(+http://www.example.com)', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
2016-06-03 16:11:48 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-06-03 16:11:48 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance dataTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\boto\utils.py", line 210, inretry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: FilesPipeline
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-06-03 16:11:49 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://myexample.com> from <GEThttp://myexample.com>
2016-06-03 16:11:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://myexample.com> (referer: None)
2016-06-03 16:11:50 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.example.com> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py",line 76, in parse    raise NotImplementedErrorNotImplementedError
2016-06-03 16:11:50 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-06-03 16:11:50 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 449,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 23526,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 15, 11, 50, 227000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/ERROR': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 15, 11, 49, 722000)}
2016-06-03 16:11:50 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to sub-class from scrapy's CrawlSpider if you want that functionality, for example something like this:

```py
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider


class LibrarycrawlerItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    file_urls = Field()


class MyCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sample'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com', 'iana.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='scrape_page'),
    )


    def scrape_page(self,response):
        item = LibrarycrawlerItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
        item['file_urls'] = response.url

        yield item
```

To understand better the how the rules work please refer to the [documenation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider), btw you can also use the `LinkExtractor` inside your `parse` method without sub-classing `CrawlSpider`.